# set autotrace on is just estimate plan?

Tags: oracle, performance-tuning, sqlplus

I've made a test:

```
SQL> set autotrace on;  << autotrace on
SQL> select * from danilo.testepart where nome = 'danilo3';

        ID NOME
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         3 danilo3


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3406920286 <<plan hash value

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |               |     1 |    65 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| TESTEPART     |     1 |    65 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | TESTEPART_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("NOME"='danilo3')
...
```

Looking for `sql_text` using the `plan_hash_value` in `v$sqlarea`:

```
SQL> select sql_text from v$sqlarea where plan_hash_value = '3406920286';

SQL_TEXT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select * from danilo.testepart where nome = 'danilo3'
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID='PLUS4294967295' FOR select * from danilo.testepart where nome = 'danilo3'
```

My question is, the `sql_text` show one line with `explain plan set..` so the output of `autotrace` on sqlplus is estimate and not the real plan used in the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html

> 8.1.2 Execution Plan
>
> The Execution Plan shows the SQL optimizer's query execution path. Execution Plan output is generated using EXPLAIN PLAN and DBMS_XPLAN.

Yes, it is possible to have a different actual plan. Example:

```
create table t1 (c1 number);
insert into t1 select 1 from dual connect by level <= 100000;
insert into t1 values (2);
create index i1 on t1(c1);
variable B1 number
exec :B1 := 2;
set autotrace on
select * from t1 where c1 = :B1;

        C1
----------
         2

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 955340196

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |   933 | 12129 |    59   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| I1   |   933 | 12129 |    59   (2)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("C1"=TO_NUMBER(:B1))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         14  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         59  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        544  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        446  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

But the actual plan was:

```
SQL> set autotrace off
SQL> select sql_id, sql_text from v$sql where sql_text = 'select * from t1 where c1 = :B1';

SQL_ID        SQL_TEXT
------------- ----------------------------------------
9677k5kzddy78 select * from t1 where c1 = :B1

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('9677k5kzddy78'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  9677k5kzddy78, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select * from t1 where c1 = :B1

Plan hash value: 1816312439

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| I1   |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("C1"=:B1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)


22 rows selected.
```